# Postgres NOW() returns incorrect time when called inside asyncio task

Tags: python, postgresql, python-asyncio

My code runs once an hour and logs the time correctly, but for some reason postgres HOW() returns the wrong time.

The code looks something like this:

```py
async def run():
    await before_startup()
    # ...

async def before_startup() -> None:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(interval_handler())

async def interval_handler():
    while True:
        logger.info("Handler:", datetime.datetime.now())
        for data in process_validity():
            pass

        # Wait to the next hour
        delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        next_hour = (now + delta).replace(microsecond=0, second=0, minute=0)
        wait_seconds = (next_hour - now).seconds
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Ensure unique per interval
        await asyncio.sleep(wait_seconds)

class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(
                Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class Database(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = None

    def connect(self):
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect()

    def fetchmany(self, query: str, per: int, params: tuple | dict = None):
        cursor = self.connection.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
        cursor.execute(query, params)
        while True:
            result = cursor.fetchmany(per)
            yield result
            if not result:
                cursor.close()
                break

db = Database()
db.connect()

def process_validity() -> Generator[DataInterface, None, None]:
    db_now: datetime.datetime = db.fetchone("SELECT NOW()")['now'].replace(tzinfo=None)
    logger.info("NOW() is:", db_now)
    for users_set in db.fetchmany("SELECT ...", 100, ()):
        for user in users_set:
            yield user

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(run())
```

The logs looks like this:

```
2023-05-20 15:00:00 +0000 INFO     Handler: 2023-05-20 15:00:00.775156
2023-05-20 15:00:00 +0000 INFO     NOW() is: 2023-05-20 13:49:35.873942
```

Note that the logger and datetime.datetime.now() get the time correctly (15:00), while Postgres returns the wrong one (13:49). What could be the problem? Over time, the gap widens.

Also, I connect via psql to the container and get the correct time; the correct time is obtained by connecting via pycharm too. In addition, after the bot is launched, the task is processed immediately, and at that moment everything is correct. Then the delta increases.

My environment: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-137-generic x86_64), Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243, postgres:15.1-alpine, python 3.11.

Comment: Are you sure this is a Python-related question? You said yourself that Postgres returns the wrong time. Have you tried a simple query directly via `psql` to verify what that returns?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Thank you for participating! Yes, I connect via psql to the container and get the correct time. Also, the correct time is obtained by connecting via pycharm. In addition, after the bot is launched, the code is processed immediately, and at that moment everything is correct. Then the delta increases.

Comment: Could this be due to the transaction not being closed? Postgres Documentation: now ( ) → timestamp with time zone Current date and time (start of current transaction).

Comment: Please have a look at this:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63549/211987  You probably want `clock_timestamp` instead of `now()`.

Comment: The problem is failure to read the docs [Current date/time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT). Also leaving a connection open for ~1 hr and 11 minutes is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with the answers in the comments and the following as a result:

1. Use psycopg2 connection pool and write a class to create a context with a connection that would close automatically after one or set of transactions or select statements
2. Use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function